# positivity of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $G(\omega):=\omega^4+2r^2\omega^2+b$, where $r,b\in\mathbb{R}$. What constraints on the parameters are needed to guarantee the positivity of $G$ for all $\omega>0$?

Answer (score -1):

First observe that $G(0)>0$ implies $b>0$. On the other hand, if $b>0$ then $G(\omega)\geq b>0$. Hence for $G$ to be positive, it is necessary and sufficient that $b>0$.

Comment: For $b=0$, $G$ is also strictly positive because $\omega>0$